# Replace comment field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to replace html of comment field. But it doesn't replace. The default comment field is also displayed.

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults');
function change_comment_form_defaults( $default ) {
  $default['fields']['url'] = ''; // this works fine
  // this doesn't work (it's added but default field is still displays)
    $default['fields']['comment_field'] = '<div class="md-form">
            <textarea id="comment" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3" required></textarea>
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </div>';
  // this works fine
    $default['fields']['author'] = '<div class="md-form mt-3">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>';
  // this also doesn't work (it's added but default is not removed)
    $default['fields']['submit_button'] = '<button class="btn" type="submit">Submit your comment</button>';
    return $default;
}
```

I am not sure why assigning a new value isn't removing previous one. (I'm not concatenating anywhere.)

---

I also tried to remove using:

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'remove_fields');

function remove_fields($fields)
{
    if(isset($fields['comment_field']))
    unset($fields['comment_field']);
    return $fields;
}
```

But it also didn't work.

Comment: The comment textarea is output through the filter `comment_form_field_comment` - maybe something else in your setup has hooked into that, and overwrites what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe try changing `add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults');` to `add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults',100);`. The third arguement is the priority in which the filter is applied. Perhaps something fires after which is changing/undoing your code.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak My following solution worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got solution! It is directly inside the fields.

Replacing this:

```
$default['fields']['comment_field']
```

With this:

```
$default['comment_field']
```

This worked fine.